# I installed jdk1.8 using jdk-8u251-linux-i586.tar.gz installer in linux, but still getting error: bash: /bin/java: No such file or directory

Tags: java

I installed jdk1.8 using jdk-8u251-linux-i586.tar.gz installer in ec2 linux machine, but still getting error: -bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory

Extracted path:/u03/bea/jdk1.8.0_251
Command used to install:
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" /u03/bea/jdk1.8.0_251/bin/java 1010

when running command getting below output: alternatives --config java

There is 1 program that provides 'java'.

### Selection    Command

*+ 1           /u03/bea/jdk1.8.0_251/bin/java

but when trying "/u03/bea/jdk1.8.0_251/bin/java -version" getting below error
-bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory